# Javascript, create cookies, and a function that will read, and increment the cookies

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have an HTML webpage saved on my desktop that uses **iFrame**.

The **src** for the iFrame points to a page on the internet, like this:

```
www.example.com/results.html?id=1&year=1900&month=1&x=1&y=2
```

I have a button on my webpage that changes the value of month and year when clicked.

So when month gets to 13, it changes back to 1 and sets the year ahead by 1. Else, it increments until it reaches 13.

```
    if (month <= 12) {
        month++;
    }
    if (month == 13) {
        month = 1;
        year++;
    }
```

Great that works, but when you refresh the page the variable goes back to whatever it was set to by default so 1900 and 1.

- `$.cookie.set('month', month)`
- `document.cookie = NameOfCookie + "=" + month;`

I need the cookie to:

1. Use nextPage() function to change the iFrame's src

   `function nextPage() {
   document.getElementById("main").src="http://www.example.com/results.html?id=1&year=" +    year + "&month=" + month + "&x=1&y=2";
   }`

I don't care about the expiration date, the path should just be that one webpage, and the domain is actually the webpage saved on my hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies in Javascript are made easier with functions design to read/write them.
Peter-Paul Koch has an example set of said functions on [www.quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).

They look like this:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

Alternatively, you could deal with `document.cookie` yourself, or you could use the Web Storage API to store your data. (Note that Web Storage may not be supported on older browsers)

You can test if the Web Storage API is available like this:

```
if (window.localStorage) {
    // Web Storage is available
} else {
    // Web Storage is not available
}
```

To store something:

```
// The first parameter is the name, the second parameter is the value to store
localStorage.setItem("month", "3");
```

To read the value back:

```
var m = localStorage.getItem("month");
alert("month = " + m);
```

For more information on Web Storage, see the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage).

Comment: More on Web Storage API, please. If I can store cookies someplace on my computer that would be fantastic.

Comment: Something about localhost and cookies isn't working. I read that I would have to put x.y.z or something.

Comment: Added more information about Web Storage. It's a bit different from cookies, but should be easier to use, and can store larger amounts of data.

Comment: Unfortunately, IE doesn't allow Web Storage for local files. You could try running a simple server to get around it, or use a different browser?

Comment: Yes I can do that with Wamp or Python but it would only be usefull if I can connect to the simple server from a different server. I am using a web crawler but it can't find the webpage if it's not on the web.